# SharePoint Online: Getting Current User Information

Tags: sharepoint-online, object-model, rest, user-information-list

What is the best way to get the current users information. With the UserProfileService unavailable in SharePoint Online what would be the best method for getting a users information.

Client was looking to use the UPS automatically populate a form. I have tried getting data from the User Information List using REST but that hasn't provided any results as of yet. What about using Access Services, is this feasible, I have started looking into it now but when trying to map to SharePoint Online as the data source the User Information list doesn't show as an option.

Is using/knowing App Model/Object Model the only way to go here? The client was hoping to not need a developer to build this, hoping they could still allow power users to build these capabilities out.

This is to support an extranet scenario so I don't think the social REST feed is going to be of help here because of the external users.

I haven't found much yet in the way of best practices or methods for getting this info with SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

Using SPServices' GetCurrentUser function you can get all sorts of fields on the current user.  Straight from the [documentation](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser), here is an explanation of how it works(which BTW I think is *brilliant*):

> How It Works
>
> The SPGetCurrentUser function does an AJAX call to grab
>   /_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True and "scrapes" the values from the
>   page based on the internal field name (aka StaticName).

Comment: ...and I'm currently using in on SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

Going to shamelessly plug my blog:

To get the current user information in SharePoint Online,

You can use the REST API to get UserProfile properties:

http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html

Or you can use the JavaScript CSOM:

http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html

Hope this is helpful